# Implementing Merge Via SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a Flat File and that will be split and will be put into three different tables, That is ok but here the problem is that if that record already exists there i need to update it else insert it , If there are any extra data other than the file then that data has to be deleted from the table.

It is same as merge statement in sql but i wanted to execute it only through package how can this be done.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I'd use 2 Data Flow tasks.  First data flow is to delete unmatched records:

- Data source points to the destination database
- Lookup task on the flat file, to determine whether a matching record
  already exists.
- Attach Lookup no match output to a task that deletes the unmatched
  records.

Second data flow for insert/update:

- Data source points to the flat file.
- Lookup task on the database to determine whether the record already exists.
- Attach your Update task to the Lookup match output.
- Attach your Insert task to the Lookup no match output.